# Python join not working if the string I am joining is more then 1 character

Tags: python

I am having trouble using python join statement if the string I am joining is more then one characater

```
var_string = ', '.join('?' * len(field_split))
print(var_string)
```

Gets me back this string if field_split is a list of length 25

```
Var - ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
```

What I really want is a string that is made up of 25 '%s'

```
%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, .....
```

I figured I could change my join to

```
var_string = ', '.join('%s' * len(field_split))
```

But that returns me

```
%, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s
```

Why is the join breaking up my text and returning a comma after each single letter?  I thought it had to do with the special characters but even when I changed the question mark to ab it split up the ab.  How do I properly take a take a string and repeat it N number of times with a comma after each repeat(except the last)

Comment: Because you are passing one long string and `''.join()` will iterate that string one character at a time, perhaps you meant `', '.join(['%s']*len(field_split))` - notice the list.

Comment: Another option: `("%s, "*25)[:-2]` or `', '.join(["%s" for _ in range(25)])`

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension, which usually makes more sense than the `*` operator with lists (and is safer in general when you start trying to multiply lists of mutable arguments; `[[]] * 3` is very different from `[[] for _ in range(3)]`.

```
>>> ', '.join(['%s' for _ in range(3)])
'%s, %s, %s'
```

Answer (score 0):

In python str.join() expects an argument which is supposed to be iterable. So when you used "?" the iterator iterates through the string character by character so all the question marks are joined by `", "`. When you used "%s" the string evaluated to `"%s"*25`  which is a string that looks like `%s%s%s.......`. So iterating character by character gave the output with alternating `%` and `s` separated by `,`. Another example of an iterable is a list(example in snipped below)

I defined field_split as 25 below.

```
>>> field_split = 25
>>> ", ".join("?"*field_split)
'?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?'
>>> ", ".join("%s"*field_split)
'%, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s, %, s'
>>> c = ["a","s","d"]
>>> ", ".join(c)
'a, s, d'
```